# MySQL db problem in Python

Tags: python, mysql

For me mysql db has been successfully instaled in my system.I verified through the following code that it is successfully installed without any errors.

```
C:\Python26>python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67517, Dec  4 2008, 16:51:00) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
>>>
```

But when I imported the mysqldb in my script its giving **No module name MySQLdb.**

Kindly let me know the problem and the solution..

I am using python 2.6 and mysql is 4.0.3 in windows XP.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Your question states that you're using v2.6, but the interpreter says it's v2.4.1.  If your script really is using v2.6, mysql might have been installed in the wrong site-packages folder.

Comment: That or you forgot to install the MySQL-python package. yast2 will do that for you.

Answer (score 2):

1) Try using your package manager to download **[python-mysql](http://www.novell.com/products/linuxpackages/server10/i386/python-mysql.html)** which includes MySQLdb.

2) Ensure `/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/` is in your [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH), e.g.:

```
>>> import sys
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(sys.path)
['',
 '/usr/lib/python2.4',
 '/usr/lib/python2.4/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages']
```

3) You seem to be using the correct capitalization in your example, but it bears mentioning that the module name is case-sensitive, i.e. MySQLdb (correct) != mysqldb (incorrect).

**Edit**:  Looks like nilamo has found the problem.  As mentioned in a comment: you might be running your script with Python 2.6, but MySQLdb is installed in 2.4's site-packages directory.

Answer (score 0):

Since you show you are running linux, but you mention that mysql is running on windows, I suspect that you don't have MySQL, or the MySQL libraries or Python bindings, installed on the linux machine.

Comment: Hi Kevin,
its my mistake to paste the code wrongly.Below is the proper code.

C:\Python26>python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67517, Dec  4 2008, 16:51:00) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
>>>